# Jsondatalistview show only last one value. How to do?

Tags: android, json

Android: I want to show all query per click in `JsondataListview` `Man activity.java` like id name and sex in `activity_viewcustom_list`. But there is show only last one `sex`.

> What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are setting the data on the same view.

Try this :

```
textView.setText(object.get("id").toString()+", "+object.get("name").toString()+", "+object.get("sex").toString());
```

Comment: Dear @Sunny, It's working now. Thank you so much for the big help!

Comment: @PhyButthry If it works can you Please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong?

Yes, this only shows the last value. Because you have added different value is same text view. That's why it contains only the last set value.

**Solution:**

You can manage three different `textView` for showing the data or show all data in the `textView`.

All value is one textView

```
textView.setText(object.get("id").toString()+", "+object.get("name").toString()+", "+object.get("sex").toString());
```

**OR**

Use three different textView for different data like this:

```
TextView textViewId = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
TextView textViewName = findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
TextView textViewSex = findViewById(R.id.text_view_sex);

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Jsoninstance);
     textViewId.setText(object.get("id").toString()
     textViewName.setText(object.get("name").toString()
     textViewSex.setText(object.get("sex").toString()
    }catch (final JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

**Note:** In this way you have to add three `textView` on your layout with id `text_view_id`, `text_view_name`, `text_view_sex`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Dear @Faysal Ahmed, It's working now. Thank you so much for the big help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing wrong because you are passing the values of different object  to the same View i.e. TextView. You should use three different TextView here to display your JSON data values.

```
textView1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
textView2 = findViewById(R.id.text2);
textView3 = findViewById(R.id.text3;

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Jsoninstance);
     text1.setText(object.get("id").toString()
     text2.setText(object.get("name").toString()
     text3.setText(object.get("sex").toString()
}catch (final JSONException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank both of you so much for the big help!

Comment: Always Welcome sir.